# Excel VLOOKUP required to filter data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am required to perform a check if all server drives are being monitored.

I have two sources of information:

1. A search that includes all Servers, Drives & Paths (Query)
2. A search that includes Servers & Drives being monitored (Raw Data)

To make this check easier I have concatenated the server and drives from both sources of data.

_

[image: Screenshot]

Additionally I have used =ISNUMBER(FIND("Hosting",D2))to check if the Path column contains the word 'Hosting'.

If the word 'Hosting' is contained in the Path for a drive that is not listed in the F column then this needs highlighted as it signifies that it is not being monitored.

**The data within C8 should be highlighted in some way.**

Comment: So in your case row 8 needs aditional highlighting?

Comment: Yes the text from C8 would need highlighted, sorry I should have made that clear.

Comment: Column F increments (with a gap) but the others do not, is that on purpose? And should your formula say D2 not A2?

Comment: Column F just includes sample data of other servers and drives that are being monitored and have been concatenated together. This column is what is being monitored currently. You are correct about it being D2 instead of A2. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting using the following rule? Assumes where "hosting" found in a path you are then searching all of F for a match and if not found then highlight.

```
=ISERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Hosting",D2)),IF(MATCH(C2,F:F,0)>0,"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE"))
```

If you want to return "Monitored" | "Not Monitored" a lazy way would be:

```
=IF(ISERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Hosting",D2)),IF(MATCH(C2,F:F,0)>0,"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE")),"Not monitored", "Monitored")
```

You could set conditional formatting then on a word match.

Comment: Thank you this worked. How could I replace the formula so that the words true and false are set to 'Monitored' meaning false and 'Not Monitored' meaning true

Comment: Lazy way for text purposes =IF(ISERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Hosting",D2)),IF(MATCH(C2,F:F,0)>0,"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE")),"Not monitored", "Monitored")

Comment: Thank you, sorry to be a pest but C7 & C9 aren't contained within the F column meaning they aren't being monitored but also don't have 'Hosting' in the path, so they aren't being monitored and equally don't need to be monitored. Basically no action required. How would that be signified? Thanks :)

Comment: Here is a really lazy quick fix   =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Hosting",D2)),IF(ISERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Hosting",D2)),IF(MATCH(C2,F:F,0)>0,"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE")),"Not monitored", "Monitored"),"No monitoring")

Comment: Or wrap it less lazily this way:   =IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Hosting",D2)),IF(MATCH(C2,F:F,0)>0,"Monitored","FALSE"),"No monitoring required"),"Not monitored")

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of the cells in column F is consistent and is `(server-name),(driver letter)` for all rows in column D, then I'd create an additional column to check your condition.

The formula in the new column would be: `=IF(AND(E1, B1<>RIGHT(F1,1)), TRUE, FALSE)`.

Then just make a Conditional Formatting rule for the additional column.

Comment: In your formula it only marks row 2 as True and the rest as false.I need it to work out that C8 has the word hosting listed in its Path and is not listed in column F, meaning that it is not being monitored. Does that make sense?

Comment: @dcraven My code should return 'true' when your condition is satisfied, if I understand correctly you mean to swap the result? If you do, just add a NOT() around my code

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work and I have been provided with a correct answer. Thank you very much for your help. Your formula will come in useful for another task i have. Thanks